# View returns an error from an abstract type

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core

**The Issue:**

The issue was connected with the `AppDbContext` class, the information from the database was not being correctly sent to the database.

**DbContext(with an error):**

```
public class AppDbContext : CentaureaContext
    {
        public  DbSet<Concert> Concerts { get; set; }
        public  DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) 
        {
            
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Party>().ToTable("Parties");
            modelBuilder.Entity<RegularConcert>().ToTable("RegularConcerts");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ClassicalConcert>().ToTable("ClassicalConcerts");
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

**Solution:**

Instead of getting only a `DbSet<Concert>` I needed to remove it and then to add the concrete implementations of this class:

```
public class AppDbContext : CentaureaContext
    {
        public DbSet<Party> Parties{get;set;}
        public DbSet<ClassicalConcert> ClassicalConcerts{get;set;}
        public DbSet<RegularConcert> RegularConcerts{get;set;}
        public  DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) 
        {
            
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Party>().ToTable("Parties");
            modelBuilder.Entity<RegularConcert>().ToTable("RegularConcerts");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ClassicalConcert>().ToTable("ClassicalConcerts");
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to get a values from model, from every classes, I should say its not true...
**Why?**
Because you should add inheritance classes (RegularConcert, Party, ClassicalConcert) to data base with dbSet and you don't need to add Concert to dbSet and create a table in database.
anyway You should add another model to database and the create method to get a values from them, then call them in controller.